# Get-ADUser filter with variable fails

Tags: powershell

I have a sql query that returns the Employee's supervisor email address and stores it in a variable. When I use that variable in the Get-ADUser query it returns nothing.

I've tried supplying the actual data in the Get-ADUser query and it works
I've tried convert the variable returned from the SQL query to string and that doesn't return any results either.

```
$SupvisorID="CFGFBT0000K0"
$QueryFmt3 = @"
Select  eepAddressEmail
 from empcomp
 join emppers on eeceeid = eepeeid
 join Location on EecMailstop = LocCode
 join company on eeccoid = cmpcoid
 join jobcode on jbcjobcode = eecjobcode
 join OrgLevel on EecOrgLvl2 = OrgCode
 Where eepEEID = '$SupvisorID'
"@

$SVEmail=Invoke-Sqlcmd   -ServerInstance $server -Database  $dbname -Query $QueryFmt3
$SVEmail

## This will not return any results
get-aduser -Filter "EmailAddress -like '$SVEmail'" | Select Name

#However, if I insert the actual value of the $SVEmail variable I get results
get-aduser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq 'RPolley@cc-md.org'" | Select Name
```

My apologies if my post is not formatted correctly. I've never reached out for help online before. My dilemma is how to get the Get-ADUser string to recognize the data contained in the variable returned by the SQL query.

Comment: What does `$SVEmail.GetType()` say? Also, check there's no leading whitespace or anything like that by printing the filter string to the screen: `Write-Host "EmailAddress -like '$SVEmail'"`

Answer (score 2):

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` returns `DataRow` object (or array of DataRows, if the query returns more than one row). 
So you have to specify which field of returned row you want to use. Try  `$SVEmail.eepAddressEmail`

Answer (score 1):

Get the property from the object.  Since you're not using wildcards, you might as well use "-eq".

```
$email = $SVEmail.eepAddressEmail
get-aduser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$email'"
```